# How can I install pepper plugin into chromium that is running from compiled src/out/ directory?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

Yesterday after 12 hours of compilation process I managed to compile chromium from source code following this guide https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxBuildInstructions
To my surprize I noticed that only two plugins installed by default; 1) chromoting viewer, 2) native client. Chromium dropped NPAPI plugin and PPAPI is not ported with source code due to licence restrictions.

I run chromium from within `./../src/out/Release/` directory in sandboxing with `./chrome-wrapper`
When I surf on youtube chromium asks me to install flash plugin that is already installed in my distribution. 
How can I use pepper plugin or flash plugin in sandboxing environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/pepper-plugin-implementation

```
out/Release/chrome --ppapi-flash-path=/opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-version=`grep -i version /opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/manifest.json | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F"\"" '{print $2}'`
```

did the trick.