# How do I install Adobe Flash for use with the Chromium browser (pepperflash)?

Tags: flash, chromium

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 and would like to use Adobe flash in Chromium (or Chrome). How can I do this? If not possible, what linux software is available that will work with flash files?

Comment: google chrome have an integrated flashplugin (latest version), chromium is using default flashplayer from the system (old version), http://askubuntu.com/questions/341428/how-to-install-flash-player-on-ubuntu

Comment: chrome is using pepper plugin to play flash recently, it's embedded in chrome. If you want to use it in chromium check out this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/424322/how-can-i-install-pepper-plugin-into-chromium-that-is-running-from-compiled-src

Comment: This is not a duplicate because Chromium needs pepper flash and not the old flash plugin which is the subject of the other question.

Comment: @deadhead1155: If someone's answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/449103/chromium-34-cant-detect-flash-plugin

Answer (score 12):

1. Install the package **pepperflashplugin-nonfree**.
2. Open a terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
3. Run the command `sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree`

Answer (score 1):

You won't need to install Adobe Flash if you install Google Chrome, it has an integrated flashplugin:

> The Google Chrome browser (32 bit) includes Adobe Flash Player
>   built-in. Accordingly, it's not necessary for Chrome to download Flash
>   Player separately.

[Source](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/flash-player-google-chrome.html)

Comment: Google Chrome and Chromium are different browsers (with the same code base though). The former has Flash integrated, the latter doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the package `pepperflashplugin-nonfree`. 
Here are the instructions:

1. Open a terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Run the command `sudo apt-get install -y pepperflashplugin-nonfree`
3. Restart Chromium

Answer (score 0):

The next working fine for me in UbuntuStudio 16.04 64 bits (the above not working)

I copy and paste from:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Flash

"As of 2015-05, the old "pepperflashplugin-nonfree" is deprecated in favor of an official, maintained, one-step package called adobe-flashplugin, which works for Firefox and Chromium and derivatives, but not for Yandex.Browser 46.0.2490.3623 beta (64-bit version) on November 2015. No terminals, no multiverse.

Add the Canonical Partners software source, and install adobe-flashplugin. See Chromium/Getting-Partner-Flash. [Chromium/Getting-Flash](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Partner-Flash)

(2015-11-13 15:15:49 by hans-hellen)"