# flashplayer not working in Chromium

Tags: 12.04, flash, chromium

I am using Chromium Version 36.0.1985.125 on Ubuntu 12.04 . My flashplayer is working just fine in Firefox, but it is not working in chromium. I get the message "flashplayer upgrade required" when I try to play flash videos. Is there any solution to this?

I searched around this problem, and tried some solutions such as:

- reinstalling flashplayer
- updating packages
- installing from software center
- copying the flashplugin-alternative.so from firefox library to chromium library
- installing `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` but got `Package 'pepperflashplugin-nonfree' has no installation candidate`
- searching `pepperflash` in the software center and couldn't find it.

Here is the output of command `dpkg -l \*flash\*`:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                                Version                                             Description
+++-===================================================-===================================================-======================================================================================================================
un  adobe-flash-properties                              <none>                                              (no description available)
un  adobe-flash-properties-gtk                          <none>                                              (no description available)
un  adobe-flash-properties-kde                          <none>                                              (no description available)
un  adobe-flashplugin                                   <none>                                              (no description available)
un  flashplayer-mozilla                                 <none>                                              (no description available)
un  flashplugin                                         <none>                                              (no description available)
un  flashplugin-downloader                              <none>                                              (no description available)
ii  flashplugin-installer                               11.2.202.400ubuntu0.12.04.1                         Adobe Flash Player plugin installer
un  flashplugin-nonfree                                 <none>                                              (no description available)
un  libflashsupport                                     <none>                                              (no description available)
```

Does anybody know the answer to this question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Adobe Flash for use with the Chromium browser (pepperflash)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/443728/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-for-use-with-the-chromium-browser-pepperflash)

Comment: @xangua I've tried all the solutions in that question.

Comment: The `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` package comes from the `multiverse` section of the repos, so make sure you have that enabled to use the package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your

> installing pepperflashplugin-nonfree but got Package
>   'pepperflashplugin-nonfree' has no installation candidate

means you have some problems with repositories. This package is the **only** way to get flash in Chromium. Do it. Try changing repository mirrors.

Comment: I used this link for the installation: http://askubuntu.com/questions/449103/chromium-34-cant-detect-flash-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Flash Player support ended for Chromium in April 2014.

But there is a way to install Flash correctly for Chromium on 12.04:
Since there is issues with adding the pepflashplugin in apt-get, we download and install it manually.

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~skunk/+archive/ubuntu/pepper-flash/+files/pepflashplugin-installer_21.0.0.242~cr51.0.2704.84-1-0skunk0_amd64.deb
```

Then install it:

```
sudo dpkg -i pepflashplugin-installer_21.0.0.242~cr51.0.2704.84-1-0skunk0_amd64.deb
```

After that, we need to edit "/etc/chromium-browser/default" and add this (including the " . " in the beginning) on a new line:

```
. /usr/lib/pepflashplugin-installer/pepflashplayer.sh
```

Save the file and restart Chromium, and you should now have flash!