# How to enable Pipelight in Chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, pipelight

I have used Firefox exclusively for a short while, after I installed 14.04 and Pipelight (Silverlight plugin) works fine. Then I installed Chrome/Chromium and cannot get it to work with them.

I tried removing it altogether, but no luck. After reinstalling it, again, only activates in Firefox.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/470581/241580

Comment: possible duplicate of [Silverlight stopped working](http://askubuntu.com/questions/470549/silverlight-stopped-working)

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/470594/65926

Comment: check out this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/424322/how-can-i-install-pepper-plugin-into-chromium-that-is-running-from-compiled-src

Comment: And to use pepper plugin in firefox check out this https://github.com/i-rinat/freshplayerplugin