# Google Chrome 35 - Protected Flash Content

Tags: google-chrome, flash, drm

Since I upgraded to Google Chrome 35 it can no longer play protected flash content. According to [OMG! Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/01/chromium-npapi-flash-dropped-april-2014) the support for NPAPI was dropped so that the adobe flash plugin can't be loaded anymore.

Is there any other way to play protected flash content besides

- Using Firefox
- Rolling back Google Chrome to version 34
- Pray for an update from adobe?

Comment: I don't know if it works, try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/424322/how-can-i-install-pepper-plugin-into-chromium-that-is-running-from-compiled-src

Comment: See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/369023/how-do-i-install-pepper-flash-on-chromium). However, since you are on Google Chrome (not Chromium), you should already have Pepper Flash built in, and so should be able to play Flash content.

Comment: Playing flash content is not the problem. Pepper flash has always worked fine but it can't play **protected** content. See [Adobe Access](http://www.adobe.com/products/adobe-access.html) for DRM in flash.

Answer (score -1):

To keep Chrome functioning, please downgrade your Google Chrome to 34.
You can download the [deb](http://mirror.pcbeta.com/google/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/) file.
Then use synaptic package manager or use the commandline to lock upgrades for google-chrome-stable package.
Chrome 34 doesn't have any glaring bugs, so you can use it safely for the next 3 months.
I am hoping by that time some patch will be added.

(from this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470594/how-do-i-get-java-working-on-google-chrome-35))